# android intent confused

Tags: android, android-layout

unable to send data , from one activity to another

Comment: you have multiple options like intent, shared preference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your current activity, create an intent

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
i.putExtra("name", value);
startActivity(i);
```

then in the other activity, retrieve those values.

```
Intent intent = getIntent(); 
String name= intent.getStringExtra("name","");
```